# WebSphere application server jndi lookup

Tags: java, jndi

I have using WebSphere 8.5.5.0. I configured SQL data source by, Resource->JDBC->JDBC providers and Data source. I have given the JNDI name in Data source. So now JNDI name for server1->node1 is "jndisql". How do I connect to JNDI using java application and create a database connection.

Comment: jndi is for resource holding (such as connection credentials). JDBC will be your connection...

Comment: InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/jdbcjndi");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection(); How to do with WebSphere?

Comment: so your question is specifically how do you access the resource? or how do you set up a connection after you obtain the resource?

Comment: How do you access the resource?

Comment: In case of a web application, the `resource` configuration can be specified in the `web.xml` as follows `<resource-ref><description>My DB connection</description><res-ref-name>jdbc/jndiname</res-ref-name>  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type><res-auth>Container</res-auth></resource-ref>`.